# Any idea what can cause javax.jms.TransactionRolledBackException

Tags: transactions, jms, commit

```
javax.jms.TransactionRolledBackException: Commit failed due to prior failure or after fault-tolerant switch, transaction rolled back
    at com.tibco.tibjms.Tibjmsx.buildException(Tibjmsx.java:582)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._confirmTransacted(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:3020)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._confirm(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:3415)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp._commit(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:2679)
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxSessionImp.commit(TibjmsxSessionImp.java:4605)
    at com.ubs.tsna.connector.jms.JmsTopicConnector.commit(JmsTopicConnector.java:136)
```

It's part of distributed transaction (not XA), other resources have committed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the problems was that EMS server ran out of disk space. 
So we had to purge some topics and the problem gone.

Comment: Got the same error but disk space and purging of topics did not help with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue occurs when Ems has been restarted, the client has reconnected the connection with the same connection id on the backup server specified for fault tolerant mode. When the client tries to commit on the sender or receiver , the above exception will occur.